# How to fix VLC and vlsub ubuntu 14?

Tags: 14.04, vlc, subtitle

I have installed VLC but the extension vlsub is not working. the version 0.9.10 only opens when there is no video playing and stay still. the version 0.9.11 appears two times and none of them open. what to do?

Answer (score 3):

Cache folder is missing. Create using the following command

```
mkdir ~/.cache/vlc
```

Comment: That's a bit of sloppy coding from VLC not to create its cache directory, but after creating it manually, VLSub did show the search dialog instead of "Empty".

Answer (score 0):

go to [VLC repository updates](https://github.com/exebetche/vlsub/pull/223/files) and copy all codes in vlsub.lua then using any text editor simply open `/home/kitori/.local/share/vlc/vlsub.lua`
file on your linux machine `ctrl+a` then `delete`  and `ctrl+v`

Answer (score -1):

I hope this fixes the problem.

```
curl ftp://ftp.videolan.org/pub/debian/videolan-apt.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb ftp://ftp.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable ./" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libdvdcss.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Install VLC and Mplayer, and their support elements

```
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-data vlc-plugin-pulse browser-plugin-vlc mplayer2
```

Install remaining Ubuntu 'restricted extras' (skip if space is critical)

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Enable full DVD support (depending on which Ubuntu release, these three packages may already be installed)

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-bad-multiverse
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. but it still did not work. some commands couldn't finish or be found.

Answer (score -1):

I think there's some problem with old version of VLSub(0.9). You can download the latest version manually from the Official VLC site [VLSub Download](https://gist.github.com/abhishekjiitr/e77d29541c55b019eb14dde9099e9401) and install it yourself, and it works just fine!
Steps:

1. Download [VLSub](https://dl.opendesktop.org/api/files/download/id/1478360358/vlsub.lua)
2. Copy to VLC Extensions Folder:

   ```
   cp vlsub.lua ~/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions/
   ```

It will be added as a menu in View in VLC named **VLsub**.